# Gesture not recognized in all TableView Cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, cell

Ok, this one may be a bit difficult to illustrate but here is the issue: I tried attaching a long press gesture recognizer on the tableView cell, and linked it in the Viewcontroller. But, the gesture does not work on every cell in the table - only 1. And the 1 cell it functions on changes (sometimes it is the first, sometimes the second, etc - depends on how many cells actually have data). If anyone can point me into the right direction it would be very appreciated.

Below is the code for handling the gesture. Thanks!

```
        if recognizer.state == .changed
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message:
                "Open Product in Safari", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let itemSku = self.itemArray[indexPath?.row ?? 0].sku
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Safari", style: .default,handler: { action in
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "\(itemURL)\(itemSku ?? "")") ?? URL(string: "")!, options: [:]) { _ in
                print("Link opened")
            }
        }))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any code related to your issue, best guess is:

Gesture recognizers - such as `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` - are distinct instances. They can only be added to one object at a time. If you try to add it to multiple objects, it will only "exist" on the last one.

You probably created one gesture recognizer and then tried to add it to every cell.

Assuming you are using a custom cell class, you probably want to instantiate a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` inside your cell init code and add it to self (or `self.contentView` or whatever view you want to respond to the gesture). Also set its target to a func within your cell class. When that is triggered, use either a "callback" closure or a protocol / delegate pattern to inform your controller that the gesture occurred.